# Tomcat not able to get ServletContext of another webapp

Tags: tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters

I am using tomcat 6 and I have two webapps. One is webapp1 and the other one is webapp2. From a filter inside webapp2, I am trying to access the other webapp i.e webapp1. My Filter code is something like below

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)request;
    System.out.println("requeted path = " + req.getRequestURI());

    ServletContext othercontext = confg.getServletContext().getContext("/webapp1");
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = othercontext.getRequestDispatcher(req.getRequestURI());
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Any Idea what I am doing wrong ? I am always getting null as the othercontext value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set crossContext = "true" in the server.xml. See the [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html) for the context container.

> Set to true if you want calls within
>   this application to
>   ServletContext.getContext() to
>   successfully return a request
>   dispatcher for other web applications
>   running on this virtual host. Set to
>   false (the default) in security
>   conscious environments, to make
>   getContext() always return null.

Answer (score 0):

Worked in a little different way for **Apache Tomcat 8.0.27**. Instead of changing its `server.xml`, it took me to update the `context.xml` file of tomcat  with the `crossContext` attribute of `Context` tag.