# Tomcat cross-service request forwarding?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I've had experience forwarding requests between separate webapps by updating each webapp's META-INF/context.xml to contain crossContext="true".

However, I have a situation now where I have webapps deployed within the same running tomcat but in entirely separate areas.  To elaborate, in tomcat's server.xml:

- app1 uses Service with name "app1Svc" with its own Connectors (to allow running on separate ports), so therefore its own Engine, Realm, and Host.
- app2 has a similar setup, with a distince Service named "app2Svc" with its own connectors, etc.

If I run these webapps within the same host, I can dispatch requests between the two via their context.xml's crossContext="true" and obtaining the relevant servlet context to forward the request to (as per [Tomcat not able to get ServletContext of another webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088633/tomcat-not-able-to-get-servletcontext-of-another-webapp)).

However, is this possible to dispatch between two webapps that essentially have to run on separate ports (without putting httpd or somesuch in front of tomcat)?

Answer (score 0):

Not in a native way, which is probably good.

You can access then by generating http requests from one to the other. For that purpose you need each of them expose some functionality over http (perhaps RESTfully). In order to make the requests you can use apache http components, or simply `URL.openConnection()`. You will just need to supply the URL (+port) of other apps to the application, so that they can make the invocations.

Comment: I suppose that would work, except that means I'd have two listener threads occupied to serve a single request, which is not very optimal.  This would also lost any request attributes already set on the request (which is not the case with standard forwarding I believe).

Comment: Can you expose services of both servlets via RMI ? This may be more efficient for inter-services communication than full fledged HTTP request if you are a on a local LAN. If you are on the same JVM, you have other possibilities opened to you, such as JNDI or - if you start your server programmatically - expose you own JVM wide registry of services.